# react native flex and width percentage different

Tags: css, react-native

In the react native,  when we handle the diffent size device, we often use flex and width percentage,like: `flex:1`, "width:"20%", what is the different between them, and when we shoud use them?

Comment: It totally depends on the scenario. You can achieve `width:20%` by having an element with `flex:1` and another element as `flex:4`, will have the same output. But again it depends on the situation. It's more logical if you use a fixed number let's say `width:100px` to adjust a button or something in a single line on a different range of devices.

Comment: ok, I understand it. But in react native the defalut unit is dp.

Comment: You're right, so you can use `width:100`, which means `100dp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex is used when you trying to “fill” over the available space.By using flex in a layout or view or any component space is  divided according to each element's flex property.Let me show you example when we use flex
[image]

In the picture the red, yellow and the green views which are inside container view that has flex: 1 set. The red view is set with  flex property flex: 1 , the yellow view is set with  flex property flex: 2 and the green view is set with  flex property flex: 3 . 1+2+3 = 6 which means that the red view will get 1/6 of the space, the yellow 2/6 of the space and the green 3/6 of the space.

We use flex where you want the width to match 100% of the parent layout when flexdirection is column as we dividing space in vertial and when flexdirection is row then it divide the space vertial.

We use use percentage where we want set some specific value of space in aspect of height and width in the view